# If bson ObjectId is passed to GridFS OpenId() in golang, i'm getting error "not found"

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, gridfs

I'm trying to read a video file from MongoDB using GridFS in GoLang. This is my code snippet,

```
    videoIDHex := bson.ObjectIdHex("5966e9ca0531713218127ddd")
    file, err := mongoDatabase.GridFS("collection_files").OpenId(bson.M{"_id": videoIDHex})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error finding the video : ", err)
    }
```

When I ran it I always got the error,

> not found

But, when I tried using ***find*** it works fine. I can able to get the document by,

```
    videoIDHex := bson.ObjectIdHex("5966e9ca0531713218127ddd")
    collection := mongoDatabase.C("collection_files")
    var file interface{}
    collection.Find(bson.M{"_id": videoIDHex}).One(&file)
    log.Println("file : ", file)
```

So, how can I solve the issue with GridFS OpenId? If it's solved, I can able to put the GridFS file to buffer and can finally stream it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `id`:

```
.OpenId(videoIDHex)
```

not

```
.OpenId(bson.M{"_id": videoIDHex})
```

`OpenId` wraps the parameter into `bson.M` by itself:
https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/9a2573d4ae52a2bf9f5b7900a50e2f8bcceeb774/gridfs.go#L197

Also, collection names should follow the naming conventions. `GridFS()` accepts a prefix as a single parameter, which is used to build 2 collections: files and chunks: https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/9a2573d4ae52a2bf9f5b7900a50e2f8bcceeb774/gridfs.go#L100

```
mongoDatabase.GridFS("collection_files")
```

search files in collection `collection_files.files`

Comment: I replaced bson.M{} with ID, and its still giving "not found" error. The snippet, `videoIDHex := bson.ObjectIdHex("5966e9ca0531713218127ddd")`
 `file, err := mongoDatabase.GridFS("collection_files").OpenId(videoIDHex)`

Comment: changing the collection name really worked! Actually, my collection name is "videos", but I was using "video.files". Changing from "videos.files" to "videos" worked for me. Thank you.